# Principal Component Analysis with numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an array, representing this kind of tables:

[image: Grid Type]

And I am trying to get a result through PCA, which Elements(e1,e2,e3) are similar to each other, which Concerns(c1,c2,c3) are similar to each other. To achieve this I'm using matplotlib and numpy:

```
var_grid = np.array(matrixAlternatives)
#Create the PCA node and train it
pcan = mdp.nodes.PCANode(output_dim=2, svd=True)
pcar = pcan.execute(var_grid)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(pcar[:, 0], pcar[:, 1], 'bo')
ax.plot(pcan.v[:,0], pcan.v[:,1], 'ro') #eigenvectors: pcan.v
```

However I got a result like this:
[image: myResult]

As you can see, concerns are too near to each other, which makes it impossible to analyse.

The matrixes:

```
pcar
[[-54.84 -14.21],
 [-10.35  22.58],
 [ 65.19  -8.37]]

eigenvectors:
[[-0.05  0.96],
 [-0.54 -0.25],
 [ 0.84 -0.11]]
```

When I do the same analysis with Idiogrid tool, result is much better:

[image: Idio]

Elemnts are in the same position with my PCA(just mirrored), but the concerns are too much different. Their values:

con_1     0.19     0.98, con_2     0.98    -0.19, con_3    -1.00     0.00

ele_1     0.87    -0.53, ele_2     0.22     0.80, ele_3    -1.09    -0.27

What do you think I'm doing wrong?